# Extracting nested data from the API

Tags: angular, typescript

**I have a main component in which I want to display the child component:**

```
export class ViewEntryAllDataComponent {
  constructor(
    @Optional()
    @Inject(ViewEntryComponentInjectorKey)
    public state?: any | undefined
  ) {
    this.allData = state?.data;
  }

  @Input() allData: RefusalOfEntryAllDataDto;
}

<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <udsc-all-data-entry-history/>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

**And the child component: (I need to display the modification history in it, it means modificationHistory with RefusalOfEntryAllDataDto:
I have this hierarchy in the API:**

```
export class RefusalOfEntryAllDataDto {
    personNo?: number | undefined;
    sisIdNumber?: string | undefined;
    entryNo?: string | undefined;
    personalData?: AllDataPersonalDataDto;
    registrar?: string | undefined;
    shiftRegistrar?: string | undefined;
    identities?: AllDataPersonIdentityDto[] | undefined;
    legalBasis?: RefusalOfEntryLegalBasisItemDto[] | undefined;
    state?: string;
    deleteDate?: moment.Moment | undefined;
    modificationHistory?: ChangeLogListDto;
}
```

```
export class ChangeLogListDto {
    changeLogDtos?: ChangeLogDto[] | undefined;
}
```

```
export class ChangeLogDto {
    type?: ChangeLogType;
    changeLogEntries?: ChangeLogEntryDto[] | undefined;
}
```

```
export class ChangeLogEntryDto {
    lp?: number;
    objectId?: number;
    registrarName?: string | undefined;
    registrarSurname?: string | undefined;
    registrarId?: number;
    entryDate?: string | undefined;
    registrarModName?: string | undefined;
    registrarModSurname?: string | undefined;
    registrarModId?: number | undefined;
    modificationDate?: string | undefined;
    state?: string;
    changelogFields?: ChangelogFieldDto[] | undefined;
    changelogModificationHistory?: ChangelogModificationHistoryDto[] | undefined;
}
```

W ChangeLogEntryDto  jest przechowywana cała historia modyfikacji.
Posiadam komponent który jest dzieckiem:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'udsc-all-data-entry-history',
  templateUrl: './all-data-entry-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-data-entry-history.component.scss']
})
export class AllDataEntryHistoryComponent {
  @Input() modificationHistory!: ChangeLogEntryDto;

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**I need to display data from ChangeLogEntryDto in the child component and then display it in the parent component.
Is anyone able to help me?
More specifically, I mean how to extract data that is nested**

Comment: You left one paragraph in polish

Comment: Could you please clarify why did you choose `c#` and `.net` tags?

Answer (score 0):

In the parent, you have to pass the data with the input:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <udsc-all-data-entry-history [modificationHistory]="allData?.modificationHistory?.changeLogEntries || []"/>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

And in the child, you receive the list, or you must have a logic in the parent to know which element of the list you need to provide (your initial code receive 1 element but your question doesn't mention how to chose the element)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'udsc-all-data-entry-history',
  templateUrl: './all-data-entry-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-data-entry-history.component.scss']
})
export class AllDataEntryHistoryComponent {
  @Input() modificationHistory!: ChangeLogEntryDto[];

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

To access child you can just use ".";

```
const toto = { titi: { tata: "hello" } };
const tataValue = toto.titi.tata; // tataValue is "hello"
```

When the parent value can be null/undefined, you can use "?" which will return undefined and not try to access to the child

```
const toto = null; // or const toto = { titi: null };
const tataValue = toto?.titi?.tata; // tataValue is undefined
```